# Tagging Drupal Images within a gallery

Tags: image, drupal, tags, gallery, taxonomy

I'm try to build a flickr style view where you can view images that are tagged with certain words. I cant seem to find a way to do this . . .

Drupal has a bunch of nice image galleries the two that i've messed with the most are node gallery http://drupal.org/project/node_gallery and gallery assist http://drupal.org/project/gallery_assist. gallery assist seems to be more popular but node gallery seems more flexible. With node gallery, every image is a node, I'm reluctant to use it because if 100,000 images were added, that would add 100,000 nodes. On the other hand, gallery assist can only use tags on the gallery it's self an not the individual images. Has anyone been able to do this successfully?

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for - http://drupal.org/project/image_annotate ?